# How to loop through elements created in jQuery to get their text value?

Tags: jquery, each

I want to loop through div created in jQuery that have the class "hour" to find the text held within each.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var hours = ["8am", "9am", "10am", "11am", "12pm", "1pm", "2pm", "3pm", "4pm", "5pm"];

    for (i = 0; i < hours.length; i++){
        //create main row div that holds everything
        var timeSlot = $("<div>");
        timeSlot.addClass("row time-block");
        //creates block on left that holds the time
        var leftBlock = $("<div>");
        leftBlock.addClass("hour col-md-2");
        leftBlock.text(hours[i]);
        timeSlot.append(leftBlock);
        //creates the text input area in the middle
        var middleBlock = $("<textarea>");
        middleBlock.addClass("col-md-9 description");
        $(timeSlot).append(middleBlock);
        //Creates save button
        var btn = $("<button>");
        btn.addClass("saveBtn col-md-1");
        $(timeSlot).append(btn);
        //crates the floppy disc icon
        var floppy = $("<img>");
        floppy.addClass("floppy");
        floppy.attr("src", "assets/save.png")
        floppy.attr("alt", "icon of floppy disc");
        $(btn).append(floppy);
        
        //appending everything to the container
        $("#container").append(timeSlot); 
    }
})
```

I tried using the .each() and the console log returns nothing although it will work on other elements on the html page that were not created dynamically. I can't seem to find any answers specifically to do with looking through objects created in jQuery.

```
$('.hour').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Any suggestions of what to try would be appreciated, I'm new to this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't added the `lead` class to any of the elements you've added to the DOM inside your `ready` callback function.

So when you try to console log the text of elements with the `lead` class, there aren't any.

Comment: Sorry, that was carried over from testing it on other elements in the HTML. It doesn't work with the hour class applied. Made that change in the code above to reflect what it actually looks like.

Comment: I've made a pen where it seems to work: https://codepen.io/josh-unit36/pen/QWEmypd - are you calling your each function inside the ready callback or elsewhere?

Comment: I have it outside of the ready function at the moment.. aaaand I just moved it inside. THANK YOU! Still grasping scope at the moment.

Comment: Right, ok. You need to have the log function be called after your elements have been added. If it is called before then your elements won't exist at the time its trying to log their text values.